# New build Asus Z87-A motherboard; PC not starting, DRAM memory LED lights up red

Tags: memory, motherboard, dram

I have problems with a newly build computer with a Asus Z87-A motherboard. We build several computers with the same configuration and all the other ones were working fine. First I thought the DRAM memory might be broken so I tried swapping the exact same memory from another (working) station but this did not solve my issue.
I also tried pushing the MemOK button as suggested in the Motherboard manual. It runs the checking procedure but when done nothing is changed and the problem persists.
Any other suggestions? Or are the DRAM banks in my motherboard broken?

Comment: This sounds like a case where the motherboard is simple defective.  If you have multiple builds with the exact same hardware and only one is not working then that single one is defective.

Comment: After using the same MB for about 40 builds I once came across a motherboard that had a metal pin bent inwards inside the RAM slot. Must have occurred during the manufacturing process when they place the plastic onto the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to [this page here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1823717/problem-build-asus-z87-dram-led.html#.) describing similar issues. It turns out the problem lies in a not properly positioned CPU. Disassembling the CPU cooler and carefully re-positioning the CPU and remounting the cooler solved the problem. The computer is booting now and everything seems to be working. 
So for others with similar problems, check your DRAM first but if this doesn't solve the issue make sure your processor is seated correctly!